# How to get Bootstrap 4 button to change without page reload

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get a Bootstrap 4 button to change into a different style without needing the page to reload.

I made a Subscribe button using the primary class, which is the color purple, when someone clicks it and subscribes, it changes into a secondary button, which is grey, although it doesn't change to the secondary grey color unless you refresh the page or leave and come back to it.

Below is an image illustrating this:

[image: Subscribe button image]

And here is the code:

```
<a href="#" id="user_subscription" data-uid="{$user.UID}" data-subscribed="1" class="btn btn-secondary btn-bold btn-xs">{t c='user.subscribed'} <i class="fas fa-check"></i></a>
{else}
<a href="#" id="user_subscription" data-uid="{$user.UID}" data-subscribed="0" class="btn btn-primary btn-bold btn-xs" style="color:#fff;">{t c='user.subscribe'} <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
{/if}
```

Is this possible to do?

Comment: using javascript, and yeah it is possible

Comment: @frankfurt thanks for the response. I was able to do this using jQuery using hasClass.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you can use HTML + Javascript to change it.
On your HTML

```html
<div id='originalButtonClass'>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" onclick="changeButton()">
        Subscribe
    </button>
</div>
```

And in your JS

```js
function changeStyleColorBlind(){document.getElementById("originalButtonClass").style... ;}
```

Comment: Please format your JS code. It should also be more complete, ie, a complete working solution.